# rel=next for "next" links on question pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, markdown

It would be really nice if all the next/prev links at the bottom of SO pages had rel=next / rel=prev on them, for use with browsers like Opera or the Firefox extensions that support this format for nice keyboard shortcuts :)

Comment: Who uses **Opera** anyway?

Comment: Some random guy from Australia.

Comment: I think the 3 people in the world using Opera can rough it.

Comment: You shouldn't think that way. Maybe this feature is included in other browsers soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the correct syntax here? Where is this documented in the HTML 4.01 spec?

Ah, found it:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Chapter 2</TITLE>
  <LINK rel="Index" href="../index.html">
  <LINK rel="Next"  href="Chapter3.html">
  <LINK rel="Prev"  href="Chapter1.html">
</HEAD>
...the rest of the document...
```

but wait -- only the oddball `<link>` tag? Does this syntax work for hyperlinks?

```
<a href="http://example.com" rel="next">
```

That's easiest, anything else and this is not worth doing.

edit: the op *specifically* said

> all the **next/prev links** at the bottom of SO pages had rel=next / rel=prev on them

We already do `rel="tag"` on links that are tags, so I am going to do the same for the pagination next and previous links.

Comment: Nope, just in the `LINK` tag.

Comment: You can find a list of all link types here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-links

Comment: FTR it's very much allowed on <a> tags, and many tools support that.  I think Opera itself may have a bug in that it only supports <link>, though