# Next button on questions pages requires lots of scrolling if you have many tags

Tags: feature-request

If you have a lot of Interesting Tags and Ignored Tags configured like I do, then on the 'Questions' page, or, say, [/questions/tagged/java/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) (java is a tag with lots of related tags, which makes the problem worse), the 1 2 3 ... [X] [Next] buttons may appear more than a full page below the last displayed question on the page, requiring a lot of scrolling just to click 'next'. This isn't browser specific from what i can tell.

Here's a [screenshot](http://i926.photobucket.com/albums/ad105/onelin/stackoverflow_scroll_to_next.jpg)

It would be really sweet if the buttons instead appeared directly below the last question in the list. Currently this only happens if the right sidebar tags occupy less vertical space than the default 10 questions per page.

Fortunately in searching for this question I found the [rel=next request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/relnext-for-next-links-on-question-pages), which gives me a workaround to constantly scrolling just to hit 'next'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to increase the questions shown to their maximum of 50 per page (option to do this is at the bottom right of the page).

[image]

Comment: thanks, that helps. I wasn't sure it would remember that setting, but it does - even across computers.