# Addition of j k l b Vi-style movement keys to SO sites, reinventing-the-wheel?

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't always use vi/m but when I don't speed drops like a rock to a pool. I once visited a site that had vi-style movement keys to move and some additional keys to focus on pictures and text. I am uncertain whether the site reinvented the damn wheel, ie vi, but what I feel I would like to move faster between SO sites and more systematically -- there better movement keys would be useful because movements are a language. **Y** `"ad?reinvented`?

*I stress the term reinventing-the-wheel because it may be that some user has solved this problem but if you are suggesting greasemonkey or bloating my base, `$ cat $you > /dev/null`, I want a simple solution.*

Comment: Related (and implemented): [rel=next for “next” links on question pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/rel-next-for-next-links-on-question-pages). What other movements do you suggest?

Comment: For reference, there is a [userscript](http://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts) that adds keyboard shortcuts.  Since you mention you don't want script bloat, I won't add this as an answer.  I also use GleeBox for general keyboard commands while navigating the web.

Comment: You have a funny definition of *bloat* there, because any "native" (ie. created by this site's owner) implementation of these functionality would not be extraordinarily different from a GM solution, since both are just JavaScript, running in the browser space. Anyway, not defining *bloat* clearly here isn't going to get you lots of answers...

Comment: Yi Jiang: "just Javascript"? Honestly, world contains much more than javascript. Your premise narrows too much the solution space.

Comment: @hhh And what? The *other* solution would probably be to use browser extension/add-ons, which, for Chrome, Firefox and Opera are *also* "just" JavaScript. So yes, it's all JavaScript, from where I'm looking at.

Comment: Yi Jiang: Sorry you clearly cannot read or you cannot understand. Have I suggested implementation in any point? -No.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you'd classify it as *bloat*, but [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/) does that and much more, on every site.

Comment: The term "every" here is very subjective, not everyone wants to use FF for obvious reasons[1]. Go for it but know the risks, me at least respect my privacy a bit more. [1] http://www.mozilla.org/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox36.html

Comment: Any other solution will still be Javascript, which will be as secure as its authors will make it. If you want 100% bug free software, don't use any.

Comment: kemp: why are you an extremist? Just an agnostic idea, no implementation or no design suggested, stupid to even suggest 100% bug free software.

Comment: I'm not an extremist, if you want Vim like navigation there is nothing better than vimperator. I also don't get your point about bug reports.

Comment: kemp: probably because you don't understand the question. Let me analyze it a bit. Even a simple design of Vi-style keys to SO sites (note Vi-style, not necessarily vi-keys) would be a markov chain, a state just as pressing `d` is different to state pressing `ESC` and each future state depends only on the current state, and if you note that an event, such as clicking v-i-n and ESC, depends on neighboring state then you already have an CA. If you want the models (note models, keys and reactions may vary) to work on all SO sites, you must design them to scale, not related to FF or javascript.

Comment: Sorry the suggestion about FF got me a bit tempered because it is irrelevant and actually junk, no matter how much pling-pling addons or polish they have. FF is a good example how you should not design software, cannot know whether it still is the same crap but me at least is not wasting time with it. I am giving you "-1" because I think you don't understand the problem, to do less not more, something I feel SO is seriously starting to need. Please, note that it is a process to design proper moves, not trivial at all. I may be exaggerating but at least I am not ignorant but open.

Comment: If nobody understands your question, you should probably ask yourself where the problem actually lies.